# ModelForm validation with clean() for field with underscores

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to implement custom validation on a ModelForm, but I'm having trouble with a field whose name contains an underscore.

Suppose I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar_qux = models.IntegerField()
```

When I try to define custom validation, I use the `clean_<fieldname>()` methods. For example:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('foo', 'bar_qux')

    def clean_foo(self):
        # Do stuff

    def clean_bar_qux(self):
        # Do other stuff
```

Doing it this way, the `clean_foo()` method works perfectly, but the `clean_bar_qux()` one is never invoked, and it seems that the cause is the underscore between `bar` and `qux`.

How can I define this method?

Comment: It is ok, are you sure that isn't the implementation itself that do something wrong? could you write the code inside that method?

Comment: @Jiloc the code I've used by now was a simple `print` to check if the method was invoked, but nothing was printed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An underscore in the field name will not stop the clean method from being called.

Note that the `clean_<fieldname>` method will not be called if the field validation fails (e.g. if you passed a string 'twenty-two' to the field instead of an integer '22'). If you print or log `form.errors` after calling `form.is_valid()`, it might show what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had this issue as well, and I think now I know why. If you read the [Django official documentation on form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/), you'll find out that each of the fields' `to_python` and `validate` are called before reaching `clean_some_field`. I got it working after subclassing the field and overriding `to_python` and `validate`. Hope someone will find this useful at some point!